# Scanner in Scala

Tags: scala, io, benchmarking

I wanted to implement [Java's `Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) in Scala. The goal for this class is to:

1. Implement a Scala collection interface (probably `Iterator[String]`?) so I can access all the Scala collection goodies like `map`, `.toList` etc.
2. Have [better performance](http://www.cpe.ku.ac.th/~jim/java-io.html) than `java.util.Scanner`

Please review my code for bugs/design advice/performance advice:

```
import java.io._
import java.util.StringTokenizer
/**
 * Scala implementation of a faster java.util.Scanner
 * See: http://codeforces.com/blog/entry/7018
 */
class Scanner(reader: BufferedReader) extends Iterator[String] {
  def this(inputStreamReader: InputStreamReader) = this(new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader))
  def this(file: File) = this(new FileReader(file))
  def this(inputStream: InputStream) = this(new InputStreamReader(inputStream))
  def this(str: String) = this(new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes))

  private[this] var tokenizer: StringTokenizer = _

  private[this] def nextTokenizer() = {
    while(tokenizer == null || !tokenizer.hasMoreTokens) tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(reader.readLine())
    tokenizer
  }

  def nextLine() = {
    tokenizer = null
    reader.readLine()
  }

  override def hasNext = nextTokenizer().hasMoreTokens

  override def next() = nextTokenizer().nextToken()

  def nextInt() = next().toInt
  def nextLong() = next().toLong
  def nextDouble() = next().toDouble
}
```

[Benchmarks here](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files/tree/master/benchmarks)

Answer (score 9):

While I would not say the code is awful, there are certainly a few areas that could stand to be cleaned up. I am not going to post modified code because I think there are areas where the "right thing to do" is going to depend on the intended use.

First of all, your description implies that this will be used as a library class in your code. Library code should be held to a higher standard than other code, and the higher standard certainly means proper documentation including full ScalaDoc and declared return types for all public methods. A proper test suite would also be good. You will thank yourself later.

Second, there is a problem in `nextTokenizer` - it naively keeps reading lines from the reader *without checking for null* (i.e. the end of file condition). This test code will show you what I mean:

```
object ScannerTest {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val test = new Scanner("ab cd")
    test.foreach((s) => println("[ScannerTest$.main] " + s))
  }
}
```

Fixing this is going to require some thought as to what the code should do, but the current implementation of `hasNext()` is going to have to be changed either way. Some would say that `nextTokenizer()` should return `Option[StringTokenizer]` and then `hasNext()` would look something like the code below. Note that if we get a tokenizer, we know it has tokens because `nextTokenizer()` checks for that and throws away empty lines.

```
def hasNext: Boolean = nextTokenizer() match {
  case None => false
  case Some(t) => true
}
```

But at this point, it should use the proper Scala idiom and just do this.

```
def hasNext: Boolean = nextTokenizer().nonEmpty
```

Also, the "next" value methods need to be rethought. Currently, `nextLine()` will return null at end of file, and the rest will throw an exception. None of that seems like a good idea.

Finally, I wonder about the constructor taking a `String`. It would seem simpler to use a `StringReader`. The way the code is now: string converted to bytes, wrapped in stream, chains to a second constructor where it gets wrapped in an input stream reader, chains to a third constructor where it gets wrapped in a buffered reader, where it finally chains to the default constructor.

It may be that the JRE's JIT compiler will reduce either approach to something equivalent, but I think something like the code below would be easier to follow.

```
def this(str: String) = this(new BufferedReader(new StringReader(str)))
```